# Can't change resolution with xrandr

Tags: linux, resolution, xorg, xrandr

I am trying to switch screen resolution with xrandr. I have output the available modes with `xrandr -q` which output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see I am currently on 1920x1080, I am trying to switch to the preferred resolution of 3840x2160. So I try to switch:

```
$ xrandr -s 3840x2160
Size 3840x2160 not found in available modes
```

I've tried switching by index:

```
$ xrandr -s 1
Size index 1 is too large, there are only 1 sizes
```

I tried adding the screen name with `--screen 0:` but that doesn't change the result.

Am I missing something or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Standard debugging tip: does it work w/ other resolutions? I notice that 3840x2160 has a "+" in the `xrandr -q` list, whereas most of the other resolutions don't. Try some other resolutions and narrow it down.

Comment: Nope, none of them work (except 1920x1080, but that just flashes the screen). + means preferred resolution of the display (so usually the native one)

Comment: Try `xrandr -q --verbose` but I'm just guessing at this point. You may also mess around with `xrandr --rate`, since 59.93 seems like an unusual refresh rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what I was missing, it needed `--output eDP-1-1`. Still not  quite sure why that isn't implied and what was operating on when I left it out, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how this glitch has happened.

This seems to reset with `--auto`;
nothing else worked and this was an easy one-liner fix:

```
$ sudo xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --auto
```

Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer (worked for me):

The modes listed by `xrandr` are fake, and you have to manually add a modeline as normal. Note the output of xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   ...
```

(we know eDP-1-1 is the laptop screen because it says 'connected', while the others are disconnected)

Note the numbers `3840`, `2160`, `60.00` (horiz pixels, vert pixels, refresh rate). Calculate the modeline by using the mathematical modeline calculator which comes preinstalled on most distributions:

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 60.00
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

copy this highlighted part (ignore "Modeline"):

Modeline `"3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync`

Give the modeline whatever name you want; we will use the name `3840x2160_60.00` in the example below, but you can change that if you wish. **However note that if you have games or software which uses LibGDX, such as perhaps some Steam titles, [you may want to remove the underscore and/or the period to avoid what may be a LibGDX bug](https://github.com/flathub/com.valvesoftware.Steam/issues/121#issuecomment-455869384).** We will now declare it as a modeline unattached to any particular output, by just copy-pasting the above highlighted part, and prepending `xrandr --newmode`:

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2400_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

Now we add the modeline to a particular output, see `man xrandr` for the `--addmode OUTPUT MODENAME`:

```
xrandr --addmode 3840x2400_60.00
```

The modeline should now appear at the bottom of the appropriate output with `xrandr` (`-q`) (you may find grep useful to confirm if there are many modelines). Now to swap, xrandr:

```
(sudo???) xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode "3840x2400_60.00"
```

**xrandr should not require sudo privileges (`sudo xrandr --output ...`), but for some reason it wouldn't work without sudo. This should ideally be avoided. If anyone has any idea why, such as maybe nvidia-drm.modeset kernel flag, please feel free to chime in comments.**

If you can't add modelines to your xorg.conf (normal way to make this permanent), you can try another way to make it permanent (which I'm not sure how, but may depend on your window manager).

---

Background:

Indeed I've noticed that `xrandr` (`-q`) will advertise modes like in your post:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +
   2048x1536     60.00
```

... and is unable to switch to them (with NO error message, unlike your example):

```
$ xrandr -s 3840x2160
 [no output, seems successful but is not]
```

I have a dedicated discrete graphics card (dGPU) as the provider(?) for the laptop monitor (as opposed to an iGPU (integrated GPU) e.g. Intel running Xorg). In particular, my xorg.conf is like:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
    #Option "AccelMethod" "none"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

My dGPU is directly connected to the screen via BIOS settings, I think.

My version of xrandr was as follows:

```
% xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Server reports RandR version 1.6
```

I solved this situation with the answer I wrote up above, mid-2023.